# Enable the play button or codelens for tests -Testing API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We migrated to the vscode [testing api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/testing) from [Test Explorer UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer). But we are not able to get code lens (like in the Test Explorer UI) or a play button against each identified test in the editor.
We add the tests like below:

```js
const filepath = "file:///" + test.sourceLocation?.file + "#" + test.sourceLocation?.line;
testItem.children.add(controller.createTestItem(test.id, test.labelName, Uri.parse(filepath)));
```

The navigation to the individual test works, but we don't see any possibility to trigger a test run from the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!
We were wrong how we provided the URI. And Range had to be provided explicitly

```js
const filepath = test.sourceLocation?.file!;
const line = testCase.sourceLocation?.line;
const testItem = controller.createTestItem(testCase.id, name, filepath ? Uri.file(filepath) : undefined);
 if (line) {
    testItem.range = new Range(new Position(line - 1, 0), new Position(line - 1, 0));
  }
testItem.children.add(testItem);
```